# How do i deserialize LocalDateTime using Gson in android?

Tags: java, android, java-time

Now gson deserializes LocalDateTime in my spring boot server to

```
"localDateTime": {
    "date": {
        "day": //someday,
        "month": //somemonth
        "year": //someyear
    },
    "time": {
        "hours": //somehour,
        "minutes": //someminute,
        "seconds": //someseconds
    }
}
```

But when i use the exact same api do deserialize it in android this exception shows up:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scmuapp, PID: 13821
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.time.LocalDate.toString()' on a null object reference
```

This means the LocalDateTime object itself isnt null, but the underlying values are. Now i know for a fact that my request is filled with 5 objects, all having both date and time, and equal values since it was script created therefore there is no reason for them to be null, but both are. Im receiving a Page generic object that is defined:

```
    private int pageSize, page, elements, totalPages, total;
    private List<T> content;
```

The List content brings the data, in this case has a bunch of "basic values" aka strings and Integers, but then the LocalDateTime just doesnt parse properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Thats obvious. The why is the question im asking. 
The value in the json is there

Comment: Mind sharing the creating script?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason. It might be android version related. I didnt fix it per say, but basically created a version of localdatetime locally in my project and that worked just fine